# Nef and big implies semi ample?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the case of a smooth projective variety, $D$ a divisor which is nef and big. Is it semi ample and if not is there a condition to add so this is always the case ?

I tried to show it using that $D$ is semi ample if its stable base locus $\mathbb B(D)=\bigcap_{m\geq1}\operatorname{Bs}|mD|$ is empty, $D$ is nef if and only if its diminished stable base locus $\mathbb B_{-}(D)=\bigcup_{A \text{ ample}}\mathbb B(D+A)$ is empty. Moreover since $D$ is big for each ample divisor we can find $m_A\in\mathbb N$ and $N_A$ effective such that $m_AD\sim A+N_A$. However I didn't manage to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not always the case that big and nef imply semiample. Zariski's example is a counterexample to this, which appears in section 2.3.A in Lazarsfeld's *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry*, volume I.

You are correct that, quite generally, a divisor is semiample if and only if its stable base locus is empty. Indeed, theorem 2.1.20 in the aforementioned book states that $\mathbb{B}(D)$ is the unique minimal element in the set $\{\text{Bs}(|mD|)\}_{m \geq 0}$.

In the big and nef case however we have that $D$ is semiample if and only if its section ring $R(X, D) = \bigoplus_{m \geq 0} H^0(X, mD)$ is a finitely generated algebra. This is theorem 2.3.15 in Lazarsfeld's book.

Comment: And is we suppose for example that $X$ is a smooth projective  surface or curve with theorem 2.3.15 ?

Comment: For a smooth complete curve big is equivalent to ample. Zariski's example is a smooth projective surface.